# MySQL MAX() with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering these entries:

```
INSERT INTO `schedule_hours` (`id`, `weekday`, `start_hour`) VALUES
(1, 1, '09:00:00'),
(2, 2, '09:00:00'),
(3, 3, '09:00:00'),
(4, 4, '09:00:00'),
(5, 5, '09:00:00'),
(6, 6, NULL),
(7, 7, NULL),
(8, 1, '12:00:00');
```

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(id), weekday, start_hour
FROM schedule_hours
GROUP BY weekday
ORDER BY weekday
```

The objective is to get a whole week (weekday 1-monday, 2-tuesday, etc...) but return the most recent entries.

So, in my table I now have 2 entries for Monday and 1 entry for the rest of the days, I only want to return the latest ones (id is an increment field), the right result should be:

```
8 1 12:00:00
2 2 09:00:00
3 3 09:00:00
4 4 09:00:00
5 5 09:00:00
6 6 NULL
7 7 NULL
```

What I'm currently getting:

```
8 1 09:00:00 < wrong
2 2 09:00:00
3 3 09:00:00
4 4 09:00:00
5 5 09:00:00
6 6 NULL
7 7 NULL
```

The id and weekday columns are correct, but the first row is showing a wrong result for the start_hour column!

Comment: This is because MySQL's `GROUP BY` sucks.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Well, the fact that the OP didn't get an *error* is because MySQL's `GROUP BY` sucks.

Comment: This question is asked several times a day.

Comment: @Strawberry All questions on StackOverflow are asked several times a day.

Comment: Your query has, in part, `SELECT start_hour ... GROUP BY weekday`. How does MySQL know which `start_hour` to select? It turns out that this is only possible because of [a non-standard feature in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html), and "the server is free to choose any value from each group", regardless of `ORDER BY` or anything else.

Comment: Just refer to the manual for a documented solution. Or google.

Comment: @IMSoP So, MySQL basically picks a random value for my row? Should I laugh or cry?

Comment: @JorgAncrath You should do the right thing; start using ANSI standard `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @JorgAncrath In most DBs, this would simply be an invalid query. MySQL is trying to be helpful, but if you learn how `GROUP BY` should work, you can write clearer SQL and not rely on this controversial feature :)

Comment: @JorgAncrath - Esseentially in this situation it picks undefined values for the non GROUP BY / non aggregate columns. The values will be from one of the rows that are grouped together, but not necessarily the one that the aggregate field refers to. It is generally consistent in which rows values it brings back, but which one it choses is not defined, and I suspect is liable to change without notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this query:

```
SELECT id, weekday, start_hour
FROM schedule_hours
WHERE id IN (
     SELECT MAX(id)
     FROM schedule_hours
     GROUP BY weekday
   )
ORDER BY weekday
```

Currently in your query, the columns in `SELECT` clause are different from the columns in `GROUP BY` clause. In standard SQL, your query is illegal and will result in a syntax error. However, MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause, which is why you are not getting an error but the output is not what you are expecting. For more details, you may read [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: Stop doing this. You shouldn't list a column in the `GROUP BY` that's not in your `SELECT` list

Comment: Well, it did the job. Cheers Aziz.

Comment: @JorgAncrath Good luck using poor practices.

Comment: I'm from Portugal, poor practices are part of my culture.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Seems reasonable to me: "find all IDs which are the max for some weekday". You can't select `weekday` in the sub-query and still use an `IN` clause, but you don't need to, because you'll never reference it anyway. The only part that seems bad is relying on the value of the `id` column rather than having an explicit ordering.

Comment: The query is fine. I would add that it works with the assumption that `id` has a `Unique` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which avoids taking advantage of MySQL allowing a GROUP BY of a field which isn't in the SELECT statement:-

```
SELECT schedule_hours.id, schedule_hours.weekday, schedule_hours.start_hour
FROM schedule_hours
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT weekday, MAX(id) AS MaxId
    FROM schedule_hours
    GROUP BY weekday
)Sub1
ON schedule_hours.id = Sub1.MaxId
AND schedule_hours.weekday = Sub1.weekday
ORDER BY schedule_hours.weekday
```